# Cloudfront Caches my S3 bucket content

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control, amazon-route53

I have a bucket that has NOT been enabled for static-website hosting.
Cloudfront points to it and I am able to view the root (index.html) of the bucket.

When I go to the Cloudfront link "xxxxx.cloudfront.net" it shows me the contents of the bucket. However when I make changes the index.html file it doesn't update  in cloudfront.

I understand that it is stored in cache in the edge location. I have set the bucket Cache-Content max-age=0 but cloudfront still seems to be reading from Cache. The TTL is set to the default of 0 for the cloudfront.

Any ideas of how I can update my s3 bucket and it will quickly be updated in cloudfront?

Comment: Problem solved by adding the following to the header of the index.html  max-age=0,must-revalidate,public,proxy-revalidate

Answer (score 0):

Is your Minimum TTL > 0? If so, it might be using that value instead.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

> CloudFront caching—Objects are cached for the greater of the value of
>   the Cache-Control max-age directive or the value of the CloudFront
>   Minimum TTL.

Comment: Hi  the TTL is set to the default of TTL=0 for the cloudfront

Comment: What happens when you set the Cache-Control: max-age=10?  Does it still happen?  Are you using the command line to hit the cache or a browser?

Comment: Hi I just solved the problem. I put the following into the header of my index.html file for Cache Control  = "max-age=0,must-revalidate,public,proxy-revalidate"

Comment: You should post this as your own answer then accept is as the correct answer.

Comment: Aye, I agree with what bruce said